# Odoo 8 and beyond. Create and Save automatically without Create and Save buttons

Tags: button, save, odoo

I´m recovering data from a third party service using SoapPY and I keep it in a dictionary structure. Data recovered has the one2many structure, similar as a sale order structure (header-lines).
I do that when clicking a custom button after filling some key values. I disabled Create and Save buttons because I want a different form behaviour. I just need to get the data and by hand save it in the corresponding tables (the header and the lines). I don't want the custom button performs the create method automatically as any button does it by default.
Any sugestion, please?

> ```
> def custom_button(self):
>
>     # Get the info from third party using SOAPPy
>     WSDLFile = "http://www.expedientes.poderjudicial.gub.uy/wsConsultaIUE.php?wsdl"
>     proxy = WSDL.Proxy(WSDLFile)
>     UIE = str(self.int_sede) + '-' + str(self.int_nro_registro) + '/' + str(self.int_ano)
>     soap_exp = proxy.consultaIUE(UIE)
>
>     # Set variables
>     str_origen = soap_exp[1]
>     str_caratula = soap_exp[3]
>     str_abogado_actor = soap_exp[4]
>     str_abogado_demandado = soap_exp[5]
>     movimientos = soap_exp[6]
>
>     mov_exp = []
>     for mov in movimientos:
>         mov_exp.append ((0, 0, {'str_sede': mov['sede'],
>                           'date_venc': mov['vencimiento'],
>                           'str_decreto': mov['decreto'],
>                           'date_mov': mov['fecha'],
>                           'str_movimiento': mov['tipo']}))
>
>     expediente = {'int_sede': self.int_sede, 'int_nro_registro': self.int_nro_registro, 'int_ano': self.int_ano,
>                    'str_origen': str_origen,
>                    'str_caratula': str_caratula,
>                    'str_abogado_actor': str_abogado_actor,
>                    'str_abogado_demandado': str_abogado_demandado,
>                    'movimiento_ids': mov_exp
>                  }
>
>      return write(expediente)
> ```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7GDv.png)

Comment: Each Odoo/openerp model has a `create` method have you tried that? Infact the button you're avoiding actually calls the same `create` method

Comment: I took off buttons from the form and I don't want to the custom button do the create by itself. I want to do it by hand.

Comment: Yes i understand, Maybe if you show some code, we could understand you better and help you out

Comment: I edited my post to add the code.

Comment: I also added the form view

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid Odoo's ORM then just go ahead and use sql. By creating and saving a record we mean the **same thing**. The write method operates on a recordset that already has been created. I see that:

`return write(expediente)`

What is this? Are you defining a `write` callable somewhere? Are you importing the method write? The write method is usually invoked like `self.write({'my_field':its_value})` where self is a [recordset](http://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/reference/orm.html#recordsets)

So, on the click of your button you can:

1) use `self.create({field1:value1, field2:value2, ...})`

2) use `self.env.cr.execute(r"insert raw sql here")` to create records in the table that you want (that is if you do not want to actually use Odoo's ORM